Can't access useRuntimeConfig or useNuxtApp in pinia store in nuxt 3
I have a nuxt 3 project in which I cannot reference process.env. Apparently we have to do it differently for this nuxt version,
variables must be declared in nuxt.config -
this is my nuxt.config.js


import { defineNuxtConfig } from "nuxt/config"
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      apiBase: process.env.NUXT_API_URL
    }
  },
  head: {
    title: 'docgen-snippet-mapping',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en',
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },
  css: ['~/assets/global.css'],
  plugins: [],
  components: true,
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],
  modules: ['@pinia/nuxt', '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'],
  build: {},
});



but thing is useRuntimeConfig cannot be accessed from a pinia store,
I tried creating a composable function and located it in composables/useEnvVariable.js like this user said he resolved it but I cannot import useRuntimeConfig, it just doesn't appear.


export function useEnvVariables() {
  const { $runtimeConfig } = useRuntimeConfig(); //
  return $runtimeConfig;
}



I also tried using defineNuxtPlugin which I also cannot import anywhere. Not even in a vue component.


    export function useEnvVariables() {
  const { $runtimeConfig } = defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    const runtimeConfig = nuxtApp.$config;
    return runtimeConfig ;
  });
  return $runtimeConfig;
}



So I'm left here not being able to use my environment variables.
my .env reads:
NUXT_API_URL=http://localhost:7209/


I can now import useRuntimeConfig in my pinia store this way
import { useRuntimeConfig } from '#app'

because I added this in my tsconfig.json


"paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "#app": ["./node_modules/nuxt/dist/app"]
    },



